# Correct function of Data-filter launched from jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I apologize in advance, but I don't speak English.
After loading the code and clicking on TEST, the Data-filter function starts, but after another click, the function does not start anymore. I would need the Data-filter to activate after every click. Some ideas? And thanks in advance for your help.

Here is my test code.

```
<div class="test"></div>
<script>
const code = document.querySelector(".test");
function test(test1, test2) {
let Text = "";
Text += `<a href="#" class="number" data-filter=".text" onClick="test(1, 1)">Test</a>`;
Text += `<a href="#" class="number" data-filter=".text1" onClick="test(1, 1)">Test1</a>`;
code.innerHTML = Text;

}
test(1, 1);
$('a').click(function(){
alert($(this).attr("data-filter"));
})
</script\>
```

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/JosVol/pen/vYQPrKP)**

Comment: Your `test()` function overwrites the content of the "code" element. When that happens, the event handlers are lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handlers are lost when the test div is written by the test function

If you want to add the event handling back in, you could move the event handling code inside your test function after rewriting the contents of the test div:

```
function test(test1, test2) {
    let Text = "";
    Text += `<a href="#" class="number" data-filter=".text" onClick="test(1, 1)">Test</a> `;
    Text += ` <a href="#" class="number" data-filter=".text1" onClick="test(1, 1)">Test1</a>`;
    code.innerHTML = Text;
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("data-filter"));
  alert("lol");
})
}
```